# Android: change fragment width programmatically in onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to change fragment width when user rotate device to landscape mode

That is my fragment:

```
    <fragment
        android:id = "@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="myPackage.MenuFragment" />
```

And that is my onConfigurationChanged method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.menu).getLayoutParams().width = (int) (getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
}
```

But when I rotate device the output is crash:

> 05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class fragment 05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   softserveinc.dbyst.reveal.Reveal_prototypeActivity.onConfigurationChanged(Reveal_prototypeActivity.java:71)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4153)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4246)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2215)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143) 05-14 03:00:51.379:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 05-14 03:00:51.379:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-14 03:00:51.379:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3117): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Binary XML file line #13: Duplicate id 0x7f050001, tag null, or parent
>   id 0x0 with another fragment for myPackage.MenuFragment 05-14
>   03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:275)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
>   05-14 03:00:51.379: E/AndroidRuntime(3117):   ... 19 more

What i'v done wrong ?

Comment: Are you using the support library?

Comment: yep, calls android-support-v4.jar

Comment: oh, damn, the problem is in setContentView...its crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your setcontentview crashes because you got the fragment defined in XML. You got a couple of options here (that I know of, I'm not a pro on this issue ;) ). You can put a FrameLayout where the fragment is and then add the fragment with a replace transaction:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_container, yourFragmentObject);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Alternatively you can test if setRetainInstance(true) will work.